# How can I write a Python script that changes my computer to dark mode based on a datetime object?

Tags: python, windows

Windows 11 does not have a built in dark mode timer, so I was wondering if I could write a Python script that does it myself. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand it correctly. Do you mean that you want to convert JSON data into a Python object. If you are using `python3`. What you need is `import json`, `SimpleNamespace` and `object_hook` function. If you want to Convert from Python to JSON you can try `json.dumps()`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I clarified my post. I know that json.dumps() function converts python objects to JSON objects, but I don't know how to pass those converted objects into a JSON file.